# Do you know about the textbook of Selberg class of Dirichlet series?

Tags: reference-request, dirichlet-series, l-functions

I have read the Atle Selberg's thesis named "*Old and new conjectures and results about a class of Dirichlet series*". At the end of this thesis, he wrote

> "A more complete account with proofs is under preparation and will in time appear elsewhere."

Does this account exist? I want to read this account because I could't understand his thesis at all. If you know this account, please show me a link.